# What exactly is a language pack?

Tags: language-support

At the end of installation, when the UI says "Downloading language packs", what are the different languages downloaded?

Answer (score 6):

Language packs are `.deb` packages which contain sets of localizations (string translations, possibly keyboard layouts, etc…), for the default installed applications and libraries. Some of these are available and installed by default, but if you wish to enable additional languages, then additional packages may need downloading and installed to enable that language. When you enable a language, only the packages for that language are downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 4):

The idea with language packs in Ubuntu is that only those translations and other language aid packages you need are installed. The alternative would be to install such packages for all available languages for all users.

With that in mind, I have a feeling that you don't consider the language packs to be such a bad idea, after all. If you still want to discuss the topic, the [ubuntu-devel-discuss mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-devel-discuss) is a proper place.

Answer (score 1):

The language packs simply install different languages that can be used on your system instead of English - it's not required and you can skip it if you want - as long as your preferred language is English.

You could contact Canonical about your concern somewhere [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/contact-us)